# Выбор элемента из динамически созданного списка

Tags: javascript, ajax

Доброго времени суток. Такой вопрос возник, при выполнении одной задачи.
Есть список товаров, который динамически выводится через ajax запрос с базы данных

```js
jQuery.ajax({
   url: "out_product.php",
   type: "POST",
    
   success: function(data) {
    
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $('#rows').empty();
    $.each(data, function(i, item){        
     
     $('#rows').append("<div class='list'>" + "<input class=" + item.id + " " + "value= "+ item.id + " > " + item.name + " " +  item.color + " " +  item.size + " " + item.quntity + " " + item.price + " " + item.price_nds + " " + "<input class='add_basket' type='button' value='Добавить в корзину'/>" + "</div>" + "</br>");
```

К каждому динамически созданному div создается кнопка, для добавления товара в корзину

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '.add_basket', function(){
  var product = ???  
   alert(product);
 });
});
```

Как мне обратится  к input именно в данном диве, класс которого создается по id из базы данных и считать его значение (будь то текст или число)?.
В javascript я новичок, если можно объясните как сделать.

Вот отработанный HTML.

```html
<div id="list">
<input class="id" readonly="" value="1"> 
<input class="name" value="23">
23 23 23 23 27.14 
<input class="add_basket" type="button" value="Добавить в корзину"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_basket', function(){
    var product = $(this).closest("div.list").find("input[type!='button']").val();   
    console.log(product);
});
```

P.S. У Вас не хватает кавычек вокруг значений атрибутов создаваемых элементов.

Надежнее назначать всем похожим инпутам, которые нужно находить в коде, одинаковый дополнительный класс:

```
... + "<input class='item-id " + item.id + "' value='" + ...

$(document).on('click', '.add_basket', function(){
    var product = $(this).closest("div.list").find("input.item-id").val();   
    console.log(product);
});
```

Comment: сделал по второму примеру.HTML отрабатывает нормально <input class="id" value="1">, добавляет класс. Но при нажатии на кнопку выдает 'undefined',

Comment: @Антон Очень хорошо. С дополнительным классом - без кавычек не обойтись.

Comment: @Антон Пардон, там же нет атрибута `id` - исправил.

Comment: -'undefined'...

Comment: Поместите в вопрос кусок получающегося html.

Comment: @Антон как сочетаются `<div class='list'>` в коде и `<div id="list">` в html?

Comment: поместил, цифры это просто сумбурно введеные данные, которые я в дальнейшем тоже помещу в инпуты и к ним мне тоже нужен будет доступ.

Comment: @Антон При чем здесь цифры? Этот html не может быть создан кодом, который у Вас в вопросе.

Comment: Да, я пока редактировал, поменял класс на id, а в функции забыл. Бессонная ночь дает о себе знать) Спасибо огромное, все сработало!!!